# Why am I getting this error “ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 4” even the code is fine?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using this code and it gives me this error, `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 4.` It is supposed to print the mean, median and mode in a csv file by using the data from the other csv file. When I use this code it prints mean and median to a specified csv file but it does not print the mode. This is the code I am using(below).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('one_hello.csv', names=['teacher', 'student',\
         's.grade', 't.average','t.median','t.mode'])

df['Star Rating'] = df['Star Rating'].astype(int) #convert to integer.

df['t.mean'] = df.groupby('teacher')['s.grade'].transform('mean')
df['t.median'] = df.groupby('teacher')['s.grade'].transform('median')
df['t.mode'] = df.groupby('teacher')['s.grade'].transform(lambda group: group.mode())
df.to_csv('two_hello.csv') #write to file
```

File 'test_one' looks like this:

```
teacher         student         student grade
Jon             marin           99
Jon             Rob             81
Jon             marly           90
Jon             Ticy            90
Bon             lue             76
Bon             martin          76
Bon             marie           56
Ton             Seri            43
Ton             Loku            99
```

I want the file "test_two" to look like this:

```
teacher         student         s.grade    t.avg    t.median    t.mode 
Jon             marin           99          90         90           90
Jon             Rob             81          90          90          90  
Jon             marly           90          90          90          90
Jon             Ticy            90          90          90          90
Bon             lue             76          69.3        76          76
Bon             martin          76          69.3        76          76
Bon             marie           56          69.3        76          76
Ton             Seri            43          69.3        71          43
Ton             Loku            99          69.3        71          99
```

But, it only prints 'mean' and 'median' on the other file and gives me error like this.

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 3049, in transform
    s = klass(res, indexer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 250, in __init__
    data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4117, in __init__
    fastpath=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2719, in make_block
    return klass(values, ndim=ndim, fastpath=fastpath, placement=placement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 115, in __init__
    len(self.mgr_locs)))
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 4`
```

Comment: test_one is same as one_hello.csv?

Comment: Both are csv files but they are different. 'test_two' should print the additional information(mean,median,mode) using the data in 'test_one'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `one_hello.csv` is `test_one` and `Star Rating` is `s.grade` this should work. I only changed the column name mapping in `read_csv()` to match the source file:

```
import io
import pandas as pd


source = io.StringIO("""
Jon, marin, 99
Jon, Rob, 81
Jon, marly, 90
Jon, Ticy, 90
Bon, lue, 76
Bon, martin, 76
Bon, marie, 56
Ton, Seri, 43
Ton, Loku, 99
""")

df = pd.read_csv(source, names=['teacher', 'student', 's.grade'], dtype={'s.grade': int})
df['t.mean'] = df.groupby('teacher')['s.grade'].transform('mean')
df['t.median'] = df.groupby('teacher')['s.grade'].transform('median')
df['t.mode'] = df.groupby('teacher')['s.grade'].transform(lambda group: group.mode())
df.to_csv('out.csv')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  teacher  student  s.grade     t.mean  t.median  t.mode
0     Jon    marin       99  90.000000        90      90
1     Jon      Rob       81  90.000000        90      90
2     Jon    marly       90  90.000000        90      90
3     Jon     Ticy       90  90.000000        90      90
4     Bon      lue       76  69.333333        76      76
5     Bon   martin       76  69.333333        76      76
6     Bon    marie       56  69.333333        76      76
7     Ton     Seri       43  71.000000        71      43
8     Ton     Loku       99  71.000000        71      99
```

Comment: Thanks! for the answer. Yes they are same, but it's still not working. It still gives me the same error. Do you think I should be concerned about any other thing besides the code ?

Comment: which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: pandas Version : u'0.20.2'

Comment: I'm was using 0.20.2 as well. So, something is different with your setup. Can you produce a self-contained example (including all data) that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your error appears to be in naming the columns of your `DataFrame` in creation, you're trying to name more `columns` than there actually are.
Another thing, as you can see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), you should explicitly set `header` to 0 if you want to replace names of your csv_file header.
without further delay, this code did the job:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('one_hello.csv', names=['teacher', 'student','s.grade'],header=0)

df['s.grade'] = df['s.grade'].astype(int) # you mean s.grade ?

df['t.avg'] = df.groupby('teacher')['s.grade'].transform('mean') #unchanged
df['t.median'] = df.groupby('teacher')['s.grade'].transform('median') #unchanged
df['t.mode'] = df.groupby('teacher')['s.grade'].transform(lambda group: group.mode()) #unchanged
df.to_csv('two_hello.csv') #write to file
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks ! but still I am getting the error. The only problem is with this line `df['t.mode'] = df.groupby('teacher')['s.grade'].transform(lambda group: group.mode())`. Based on your experiences, do you think I should be concerned about any other thing besides the code ? Because the code looks fine to me too.

Comment: well i don't think it's related to the code in that case, i mean it worked fine for me, you should verify you input csv file, i used the exact same example you gave